# How can I make UINavigationController transparent in one view controller only?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to make the `NavigationBar` transparent in only one `ViewController`. However, upon changing the `NavigationBar` in a single `ViewController`, the entire `navigationController` becomes transparent and after a few second crashes.Here is my block of code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }



override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

    }
```

It crashes in line

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: you can make custom navigation controller for that particular view controller

Comment: Please clarify it a little more. Thanks

Comment: Crashing on that line means you navigation controller is nil, are you sure you don't have any other code that is setting it to nil?

Comment: Crashing because of setting nil in place of imageView

Comment: The same code works for UITableViewController. The only difference is that I will have to set the delegate of TableView to nil in viewDidDisppear method. I can't find a workaround for UIViewController

Answer (score 7):

We can achieve this requirement like this :

In Which `UIViewController` we want to clear the NavigationBar Color should be clear in that `UIViewController` we need to write these code in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` method

In `viewDidLoad` method we need to write that for better appear result if we did not write put the code snippet then the `navigation bar` color will change after will view shown.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

When we move to other screen(push another `UIViewController`) on the same `UINavigationController` we need to set the `barTintColor` otherwise it will be appear as black color.

Answer (score 3):

Try given code to make navigation bar transparent in swift :-

```
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Hope this code will help you.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: You got some forced unwraps in your solution, but your solution works for me.

Comment: Works for Swift 5.x. Wrap it in a UINavigationController extension to make it easier to call

Answer (score 2):

In `viewWillAppear`,

```
  self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

and in `viewWillDisappear`

```
  self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (247.0 / 255.0), green: (247.0 / 255.0), blue: (247.0 / 255.0), alpha: 1)  // this is default bar color you can set your desired color if you are using custom color for navigation bar
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Recommend putting in `viewWillDisappear` instead to avoid the slight delay. Agree with approach though

Comment: Done ! Changed didaopear to willappear

Comment: a small problem though, setting the backgroundColor to clear makes the navbar black.